# python iteration for a derivative matrix

Tags: python

This is my code. I want to iterate the function f(x) and its derivative  matrix simultaneously both in matrix form. How can i do that?

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp

x=sp.Symbol('x')
k=[]
def m1(x):
    return 4*x**2 + 8*x
def m2(x):
    return 8*x**2 + 6*x
def m3(x):
    return x**2 + 10*x
def m4(x):
    return 10*x**2 + x



def dm1(x):
    return sp.diff(m1(x),x)
def dm2(x):
    return sp.diff(m2(x),x)
def dm3(x):
    return sp.diff(m3(x),x)
def dm4(x):
    return sp.diff(m4(x),x)

def f(x):
    return([[m1(x),m2(x)],[m3(x),m4(x)]]) # function matrix

def k(x):
    return ([[dm1(x),dm2(x)],[dm3(x),dm4(x)]]) # derivative matrix
```

Comment: what is it exactly you need? do you mean by iterate the Newton iterative solver ? If so what have you done so far to attempt this ?

Comment: yes. exactly.  i want to use a nonlinear inversion equation to solve my problem. i can iterate the function matrix easily by a for loop but cant iterates the derivative.  at the end what i need is to use the gauss newton method for solving my equation

Comment: with 2 variables x1 and x2 ? Because usually the function is a vector and the derivative is a matrix. Which means for 4 functions. You usually have a 4x1 vector and a 4x4 derivative matrix for 4 distinct variables

Comment: first, i have to solve with one variable just x.  then maybe in next  stage I  may need  2 variable

Comment: why do you need a matrix of functions then ? You need to have a 1 to 1 function to variable. Or you want to solve this 4 times for 4 different results?

Comment: hi. I am actually doing radiative transfer modeling (atmospheric science). This is my first step in non linear inversion . basically, instead of these functions (these are just example), i have to use the real data. before that i need to do a test version . Thats why i am doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp

x=sp.Symbol('x')
k=[]
tol = 1e-3

def m1(x):
    return 4*x**2 + 8*x
def m2(x):
    return 8*x**2 + 6*x
def m3(x):
    return x**2 + 10*x
def m4(x):
    return 10*x**2 + x


def dm1(val):
    return m1(x).diff(x).subs(x,val)
def dm2(val):
    return m2(x).diff(x).subs(x,val)
def dm3(val):
    return m3(x).diff(x).subs(x,val)
def dm4(val):
    return m4(x).diff(x).subs(x,val)


def f(x):
    return [m1(x), m2(x), m3(x), m4(x)] # function matrix

def k(val):
    return [dm1(val), dm2(val), dm3(val), dm4(val)] # derivative list

x_bar = 5.
x_results = []

for i in range(0,4):
    h=1
    x_temp = x_bar
    print(x_temp)
    while (abs(h) > tol):
        h = -1.*f(x_temp)[i]/k(x_temp)[i]
        print(h)
        x_temp = x_temp + h
    x_results.append(x_temp)
print(x_results)
print(f(x_results[0]))
```

**EDIT:** the above solves every function individually and not all together for 1 variable like it would in linear seismic inversion, the following should solve it the correct way:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp

x=sp.Symbol('x')
k=[]
tol = 1e-3

def m1(x):
    return 4*x**2 + 8*x
def m2(x):
    return 8*x**2 + 6*x
def m3(x):
    return x**2 + 10*x
def m4(x):
    return 10*x**2 + x


def dm1(val):
    return m1(x).diff(x).subs(x,val)
def dm2(val):
    return m2(x).diff(x).subs(x,val)
def dm3(val):
    return m3(x).diff(x).subs(x,val)
def dm4(val):
    return m4(x).diff(x).subs(x,val)


def f(x):
    return [m1(x), m2(x), m3(x), m4(x)] # function matrix

def k(val):
    return [dm1(val), dm2(val), dm3(val), dm4(val)] # derivative list

x_start = 5.
F = np.array(f(x_start))
dF = np.array(k(x_start))
dx = 1.
x_temp = x_start


while abs(dx) > tol:
    make_square = np.dot(np.transpose(dF),dF)
    print(make_square)
    print(type(dF))
    if make_square is not np.ndarray:
        inverse = 1/make_square
        #inverse = np.linalg.inv(make_square)
    else:
        inverse = np.linalg.inv(make_square)
        #inverse = 1/make_square
    inv_trans = np.dot(inverse,np.transpose(dF))
    dx = -1.*np.dot(inv_trans, F)
    print(dx)
    x_temp = x_temp + dx
    F = np.array(f(x_temp))
    dF = np.array(k(x_temp))
print(x_temp)
```

Comment: they all solve for `x=0` because 0 is one solution to all your functions `m1` to `m4` change the functions at will and check the solutions in `x_results` to see how it changes. You will notice that the starting point `x_start` influences the results. For example the equations have all negative solutions so if you start with `x_start = {positive float}` all the answers will come up as `0` but if you start at `-15.` you will get all negative results instead.

Comment: Hey I had done a mistake, I reviewed the algorithms from: [Linear seismic inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_seismic_inversion). If I can do it in 20 mins from a wiki page, you can. Good Luck.

Comment: Theoretically, linear seismic inversion should work on `n` variable with `m` functions. In my case I had `m=4` and `n=1` (4 functions and 1 variable): This leads to the following matrix manipulation: `[1x1] = ( [1x4]·[4x1] )⁻¹ · [1x4] · [4x1]`. For higher numbers of variables and/or functions follow the quations in the link.